# Only integer numbers allow print in input

Tags: angularjs, input, kendo-ui

I am use AngularJS and Kendo UI. I want to print only integer numbers in my input component. I have tried using regular expressions but it did not help me.

This my config for input:

```
input(
    ng-pattern='vm.regexp'
    min='1'
    ng-model='vm.maxContentCounter'
)
vm.regexp = /^(0|[1-9]\d*)$/;
```

This input allows print comma and dots, and I can print value less then `1`. How I can allow print only integer values?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="text" valid-decimal-number ng-model="Amount"  ng-blur="ConvertToDecimal()">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.ConvertToDecimal = function (val) {
 if(isNaN($scope.Amount)){
  alert("given input is not a number");
  return;
 }
        var num = Number($scope.Amount);
        var dupNum=Math.floor(num);
        if(num !=dupNum){
        alert("given input is not a number");
  return;
        }
        $scope.Amount=num;
    }
}]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for answer. This solution check input text after print value, it is possible allow to print only integers numbers?